# How to initialize default data in ES5 Redux reducer?

Tags: javascript, redux, ecmascript-5

For the time being I can't use ES6/ES2015 and I'm stuck with ES5 for writing Redux reducers. Since the state parameter of a reducer has to be immutable, even when it's undefined, I came up with the following pattern:

```
function myState( state, action ) {
    if ( typeof state === 'undefined' ) {
        return myState( { value1: 'foo', value2: 'bar' }, action );
    }
    // actual state calculation here
}
```

Any alternative suggestions or comments on how to ensure a default value with ES5?

**Edit:** After some questions and suggestions: the reason I do a recursive call is that I take the "state is immutable" very seriously. So even when the `state` parameter is `undefined`, I don't change the parameter variable itself. Am I taking the immutability too far?

Comment: Why do you call `myState` again instead of using `state={ value1: 'foo', value2: 'bar' }`? What is the expected advantage/purpose of that?

Comment: That would change the `state`variable which should be immutable. Or maybe I take immutability too far?

Comment: Depends from what perspective you look at the `myState`. If it is from the calling side then you might need to clone `state` if it is not `undefined` to make sure that it won't be changed within the `myState` or any other function where you pass `state` to.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Redux doesn’t force you to use the default argument syntax. It only cares that when it gives you `undefined` as the state, you return something else so that your app is able to boot up with an initial state tree.

This function in ES6:

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT':
    return state + 1
  case 'DECREMENT':
    return state + 1
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

Is equivalent to this function in ES5:

```
function counter(state, action) {
  if (state === undefined) {
    state = 0
  }

  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT':
    return state + 1
  case 'DECREMENT':
    return state + 1
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

A nice way to verify this is to [run this code through the Babel REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%20%20%20%20function%20counter(state%20%3D%200%2C%20action)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20switch%20(action.type)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'INCREMENT'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state%20%2B%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'DECREMENT'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state%20%2B%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20default%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20state%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A).

---

> The reason I do a recursive call is that I take the "state is immutable" very seriously. So even when the state parameter is undefined, I don't change the parameter variable itself.

There is no need for a recursive call here. I think your question may contain some confusion about the **difference between mutation and reference assignment.**

When you write

```
var x = { lol: true }
x.lol = false
```

you are **mutating** the `x` object. This is what Redux doesn’t allow.

However when you write

```
var x = { lol: true }
x = { lol: false }
```

the original object stays intact. `x` “binding” (also known as a “variable”) just starts *pointing at* a different object.

Redux doesn’t care if you change what `state` argument refers to. It is local to your function. Whether you return it or not, changing the reference fine **as long as you don’t mutate the actual objects or any objects inside it**.

Just changing what the variable refers to does not mutate the objects:

```
// good: local variable called "state" refers to a different number
state = state + 1

// good: local variable called "state" refers to a different array
state = state.concat([42])

// good: local variable called "state" refers to a different string
state = state + ", lol"
```

However changing something **inside the object itself, or objects it links to**, whether deeply or not, is a mutation, and is not allowed by Redux:

```
// bad: object that local variable "state" refers to has been mutated
state.counter = state.counter + 1

// bad: object that local variable "state" refers to has been mutated
var sameObjectAsState = state
state.counter = state.counter + 1

// bad: array that local variable "state" refers to has been mutated
state.push(42)

// bad: array that local variable "state" refers to has been mutated
var sameArrayAsState = state
sameArrayAsState.push(42)

// bad: object that is linked from the object that local variable "state" refers to has been mutated
state.something.deep.counter = 42

// bad: object that is linked from the object that local variable "state" refers to has been mutated
var somethingDeep = state.something.deep
somethingDeep.counter = 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be something like this:

```
var initialState = { value1: 'foo', value2: 'bar' };
function myState( state, action ) {
  state = state || initialState;
  // actual state calculation here
}
```

Comment: Would putting `initialState` inside `myState` be the better incapsulated option?