# Changing the reference of a js function's argument

Tags: javascript, redux, functional-programming

Lately I write react-redux apps and as a react developer I write pure, functional and predictable code. Even though I do like the experience I've got a doubt whether my code is still handsome or not.

So I have a tree in my state and I need to update a bunch of nodes in the tree. Let's say the tree's API provides a **pure** method `pureUpdate(path, newNode, tree) => newTree` which return new tree with the node updated. In ths case my reducer method might look like

```
function updateNodes(tree, updateRules) {
    updateRules.forEach(updateRule => {
        const { path, node } = updateRule;
        tree = pureUpdate(path, node, tree);
    });
    return tree;
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's the best could be done.

The first thing which looks nasty is `tree = pureUpdate(path, node, tree);`. It looks like mutating a parameter, which is discouraged, but I am just reassigning
the reference, ain't I? It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641160/3272018) in the second part of the answer. But although this trick might be ok, [in this discussion](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/641#issuecomment-167827978) said that such code might be unoptimized and reassigning parameters might cause performance issues ([more info with examples](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)). The simplest fix occured to me is to use an extra variable which will be a clone of the tree.

```
function updateNodes(tree, updateRules) {
    let newTree = someCloneFunc(tree);
    updateRules.forEach(updateRule => {
        const { path, node } = updateRule;
        newTree = pureUpdate(path, node, newTree);
    });
    return newTree;
}
```

The question is if I don't miss anything and my code is still pure, handsome and will not cause any issues.

Comment: If you want to do purely functional programming, **never** use `forEach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're at all concerned about performance, I would not clone `tree` just to avoid reassigning a parameter.

While you can use `forEach` here and reassign the parameter, `reduce` is the correct functional abstraction for your use case, and it's generally a better and more useful abstraction than `forEach` since it can (and should) be used purely, whereas `forEach` is always about side effects.

A solution based on `reduce` makes the question of whether or not to clone and or reassign a function parameter completely moot, as well.

Here's a working `reduce` solution - no parameter reassignment, no `forEach` side effects and no reason to clone `tree`:

```
const updateNodes = (tree, updateRules) =>
  updateRules.reduce(
    (acc, { path, node }) => pureUpdate(path, node, acc),
    tree // initialize acc (the accumulator)
  )
```